# is it possible to "extend" a profile in a child module?

Tags: java, maven

say i have a parent pom A, with profiles win32 and win64 activated by os:

```
<profile>
    <id>windows32</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>windows</family>
            <arch>x86</arch>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <envClassifier>win-x32</envClassifier>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>windows64</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>windows</family>
            <arch>amd64</arch>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <envClassifier>win-x64</envClassifier>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

those profiles define env. variables like ${envClassifier} etc.
say that parent module has a child module B which would like to define some extra stuff IN ADDITION on win64:

```
<profile>
    <id>windows64</id>
    <properties>
        <jreName>jre6u27.zip</jreName>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

can i somehow extend the win64 profile from the parent, or am i doomed to copy-and-paste it along with its activation section and everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apparently its simply impossible.
i found a good explanation here - http://www.dashbay.com/2011/03/maven-profile-inheritance/

Answer (score 7):

I just checked this case using [mvn help:effective-pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html).

Provided you specify `<activation>` section for the child profile the same way as for the parent profile, properties of these 2 profiles will be merged.

Comment: true, but the activations are most of what i dont want to repeat :-)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work based on profile name solely.